# Why does a combination of `textsc` and `texttt` cause an "Undefined control sequence." error?

Tags: math-mode, errors

Consider this MnotWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand*{\fnn}[1]{\text{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\Ker}[1]{\textsc{ker}(\fnn{#1})}

\begin{document}
     $\Ker{f}$
\end{document}
```

It produces the error:

> Undefined control sequence. $\Ker{f}

However, this compiles just fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand*{\fnn}[1]{\text{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\Ker}[1]{\textsc{ker}(#1)}

\begin{document}
     $\Ker{f}$
\end{document}
```

Why?

Comment: \text needs the amsmath package.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah, I'm using TeXStudio...

Comment: it's depressing that despite the fact that I have never even seen that editor and you didn't mention it I can guess which editor you use by the way you misread an error message. I don't understand why they don't fix that:(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `\text` macro requires `amsmath` (or at least `amstext` that `amsmath` loads).

However, once `amsmath` is loaded, `\text` becomes redundant and `\texttt` suffices also if `\fnn` is in a subscript or superscript. You should consider `\mathtt`, though. The reason should be clear from the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\fnn}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Ker}[1]{\textsc{ker}(\fnn{#1})}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

Some text with $\Ker{f}$ and $X_{\fnn{f}}$

\begin{theorem}
Some text with $\Ker{f}$ and $X_{\fnn{f}}$
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

As you see, the italic context also acts on the argument to `\fnn`. Adding `\text` would do nothing better.

[image]

Here's a possibly better definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\fnn}[1]{\mathtt{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Ker}[1]{\operatorname{\textsc{ker}}(\fnn{#1})}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

Some text with $\Ker{f}$ and $X_{\fnn{f}}$

\begin{theorem}
Some text with $\Ker{f}$ and $X_{\fnn{f}}$
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are not short of math groups, adding

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsc}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{sc}
```

would be even better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsc}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{sc}

\newcommand*{\fnn}[1]{\mathtt{#1}}
\newcommand*{\Ker}[1]{\operatorname{\mathsc{ker}}(\fnn{#1})}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

Some text with $\Ker{f}$ and $X_{\fnn{f}}$

\begin{theorem}
Some text with $\Ker{f}$ and $X_{\fnn{f}}$
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same, but with the “easy version” above you might risk shape changes in case the context where you use `\Ker` is italic or boldface and the font family you use provides variant shape/weight for small caps.

Note: I didn't load `lmodern` just to make the example more general. It would be the same with it.